# How to detect expired PayPal subscription in React & Flask?

Tags: reactjs, flask, paypal, payment, subscription

I'm working on a website and users have the possibility to buy a premium subscription. I use React for Front and Flask for Back. I already succeeded to create subscription button by using  react-paypal-button-v2.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-button-v2

```
                                    <PayPalButton
                                         options={{
                                             vault: true,
                                             clientId: "ID OF SELLOR",
                                             currency: "EUR"
                                         }}
                                         createSubscription={(data, actions) => {
                                             return actions.subscription.create({
                                                 plan_id: 'ID OF MY PLAN'
                                             });
                                         }}
                                         onApprove={(data, actions) => {
                                             return actions.subscription.get().then(function(details) {
                                                 return axios.post('/api/payment', {
                                                     user_id: localStorage.getItem('id');,
                                                     order_id: data.orderID,
                                                     subscription_id: data.subscriptionID
                                                 })
                                                     .then(function (){
                                                         document.location.href="/";
                                                         console.log(data);
                                                     })
                                             });
                                         }}
                                     />
```

The called api changes the premium column to true in my db. Now I want to detect if subscription  is canceled or expired, turn back the premium column of the user to false.

NB: I use postgreSQL

```
@payment.route('', methods=['POST'])
def paypal_payement():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        req = request.get_json(force=True)
        today = datetime.now()
        id_user = req.get('user_id')
        id_order = req.get('order_id')
        id_subscription = req.get('subscription_id')
        user = models.Utilisateur.query.filter_by(id=id_user).first()
        order = models.Commandes(id_order, id_user, id_subscription, today)
        db.session.add(order)
        user.premium = True
        db.session.commit()

    return 'SUCCESS'
```

Do you have a solution for me ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [webhook listener](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions) and register for the `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED` event.